How to make fast scroller that has fixed thumb size as dataset increases
So I added a fast scroller to my recyclerview
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:fastScrollHorizontalThumbDrawable="@drawable/fast_scroll_thumb"
    app:fastScrollHorizontalTrackDrawable="@drawable/fast_scroll_track"
    app:fastScrollVerticalThumbDrawable="@drawable/fast_scroll_thumb"
    app:fastScrollVerticalTrackDrawable="@drawable/fast_scroll_track"
    app:fastScrollEnabled="true" />

However the problem I'm facing is that the thumb size decreases as the dataset grows eventually making impossible to use. I tried this other library other users suggested implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.fastscroll:library:1.3.0'. However when I try to use me.zhanghai.android.fastscroll.FastScroller in the XML code. I get this error Cannot resolve class me. zhanghai. android. fastscroll. FastScroller . I know I have the right library, because  other layouts like me.zhanghai.android.fastscroll.FastScrollScrollView and me.zhanghai.android.fastscroll.FixOnItemTouchListenerRecyclerView do show up. Maybe that first one I tried use is no longer present? I'm just looking to have a fast scroller with a thumb that doesn't change it's size even if it requires a custom fast scroller.
